# how to display all values from a sql table but add the values of duplicate entries in other colums

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql table called **bids**

I have the the following colums, **B_id, Uid, Fid, Amount**.

B_id will auto increment by default, Uid = user id, Fid = field id, and amount is the int submitted into the field.

So I may have a table like the folowing

1 1 1 1 (the first 1 = **B_id**, 2nd 1 = the **user**. third = the **field** and the 4th = **amount**)
2 1 2 1 (same as above but in a different field
3 2 1 1 (same as the first but with a different user)
4 2 2 2 (same user as above but in different field and different amount)
5 1 1 1 (same as first row)

ok so what I want to do is user a statement to select all submissions by a given user. 
so something like "select * From (bids) where Uid='1'"

Which will return
1 1 1 1
2 1 2 1
5 1 1 1
(all rows where uid 1 has entered an amount into any field)

but I want the amounts submitted in the same fields to be added together, (I wont need the B_id nor the uid)

So I need the above table to look like

1 2 (user submit 3 amounts in total **2 amount** into **field 1**)
2 1 ( and **1 amount** in **field 2**)

So what php can I use to get the table from how I have it to how I want it?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you need to do this in PHP or can you do it in the query itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this just with the query (which is where it belongs, in my opinion rather than the PHP) it might look like this;

```
SELECT 
    Bids.[FID]
    ,SUM(Bids.[Amount]) AS AmountSum
FROM
    Bids
WHERE
    Bids.[UID] = 1
GROUP BY
    Bids.[FID]
```